# C2DM notification issue

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I am using C2DM for push notifications with android 2.3.3. I have registered successfully with C2DM server. The Android app is working fine. I am using wifi.

Sometimes Google C2DM responds properly to send notification and I receive notification on my app and sometime C2DM is not responding properly.

Comment: refer http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/c2dm.html

Comment: C2DM has been officially deprecated as of June 26, 2012.Use GCM instead.Here is the [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html)